# How to approach potential PhD advisors when you have submitted cranky looking paper?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, interpersonal-issues

I am a master student trying to approach potential PhD advisors in Canada. Unfortunately or not, I believe I have solved an important problem in my field. I have submitted my work to a journal, awaiting a response. If this does not look cranky enough, I also had bad grade in my  thesis, and my undergraduate major is not in that field.

The real question is, should I attach my manuscript in my email to the professors to show that I am not a crank (or the opposite)? Because I can't put it on arxiv (a signal that I am a crank), so the only way for professors to verify that I have potential is to show I have research experiences.

Comment: Why do you think it is "cranky"?

Comment: Arxiv is not for cranks, that's vixra.

Comment: @Buffy I assume the work done by someone who is not experienced and claim themselves solving important problem are cranky

Comment: This use of “cranky” is funny: lots of folks are cranky before the first cup of coffee!

Comment: The words "crank" and "cranky" are also funny in their relationship in that the latter is *not* the adjective of the former. If you're a crank, you're a quack. If you're cranky, you're a grouch.

Comment: Can't you get advice about the quality of your paper from your Master's thesis advisor?

Comment: If this is regarding your questions on MO then I'm afraid I suspect you have misunderstood the problem. That doesn't necessarily make you a crank, but it does mean that you need to be willing to learn some of the basics rather than just shooting for the open problem (which may also be less important/striking than you think)

Comment: As someone who has supervised PhD students in maths in Canada: I think that what people are looking for is a combination of technical ability, self-motivation/ambition, but also the ability to recognize one's mistakes and learn from them. I have been aware of cases of people who had the second, were a bit weak in the first, and were far too deficient in the third, and these cases did not work out well for either the student or the supervisor

Comment: Finally, I think your reasoning concerning the arXiv is flawed. Given how long it can take to get formal referee feedback on a submitted article, if you want to find out if there are mistakes in something you have done, posting to arXiv may be a much quicker way to get feedback. Yes, there is a risk that if you have made a mistake then this becomes public. But in that case, an honest "retraction" of the arXiv submission shows you can receive feedback and act appropiately, while the original posting shows ambition and self-motivation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most cranks actually assume that they are not. I don't think you should judge yourself too harshly until you get feedback from the referees.

But, I wouldn't send the manuscript in a first contact. You want that contact to be very short so that it is easy to respond to. Say something about your area of interest and that you have been working on some interesting problems. Offer to send a manuscript, but don't attach it unless asked.

It is too easy to discard blind emails if they seem to require any difficulty to analyze and answer.

Here is something about me. I'm interested in xyz, as you are and would like to discuss whether you can serve as my advisor. I can send along some recent work if requested. Thank you.

Comment: If I attach my resume, they will still find out, is that going to hurt my chances?

Comment: Impossible to say. But if you are awaiting response then the paper is just "work in progress" and should be classified like that.